# Recording audio with iPhone via input cable from laptop or similar source (not a microphone)

Tags: iphone, mac, audio

For example, when I create a Vine video I would like to input a clean music track. Ideally I would just hit play on Spotify and then hit record on Vine and have the track from Spotify be the background for my Vine.

**I envision this as a cable that could go from my laptop to my iPhone. The audio is outputting from my laptop and inputting to my iPhone.**

I don't believe such a thing exists. Maybe there is some intermediate tech I can stick in between my laptop and iPhone to serve this purpose? Something like a mixer, but hopefully significantly cheaper.

Comment: have you tried a regular male 3.5mm aux cable?

Comment: I will give it a try. Have you had any experience with connecting one from a Mac to an iPhone for recording purposes?

Comment: i did it the other way around so it is possible, I'm just not sure if the apps you're using can handle it, i don't know why they wouldn't tho, i used my ipad as i microphone to record on my mac